# protocol as parameter type in swift conflicts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I am using external SDK(by including their xcode project in my project).
The SDk was working properly in objective-c, but when I switched to swift, I am getting following problem.

Whenever I implementing delegate method where parameter is of type protocol, xcode suddenly gives error to object declaration of that Class which declared globally i.e. not in any function. If I comment that particular delegate method I will not get any error and it compile/executes successfully.

Please check the following swift code followed by my # comments

```
//CustomView is subclass of UIView
        var customview : CustomView = CustomView() // #1 error as : Use of undeclared type CustomView
        @IBAction func showCustomView(sender: AnyObject) 
        {    
        // CustomView configurations 
        }

    #pragma CustomView Delegates
        func CustomViewShown(view: AnyObject!) /// #2 delegate work properly
        {

        }

        func CustomView(view: AnyObject!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) 
    // #3 if I keep this method uncommented it gives error to #1 line  
    // if I commented this method all other works fine without error.
        {

        }
```

Surprising thing is all the above delegate and SDK works fine for objective-C but not for swift.

**On the basis of my little research, I am concluding that,**
We can not use the Class name and method name same in swift, i.e. in my case its CustomView. If I am using CustomView for declaring object, I can not use it as method name.

so someone please verify that, I am correct or not ? and what is solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially a name conflicting problem.

Inside of your class declaration, `CustomView` is a method name, but not a class name. So, basically, your assumption is correct.

But, you have a workaround.

Let's suppose `CustomView` is declared in the SDK. And that is a framework named `SomeSDK`. Then you can reference the `CustomView` like this:

```
import SomeSDK

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customview: SomeSDK.CustomView = SomeSDK.CustomView()

    func CustomView(view: AnyObject!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    }
}
```

If you don't want to prefix `SomeSDK.` everywhere, you can `typealias` it:

```
import SomeSDK

typealias SDKCustomView = CustomView // you can use `CustomView` here because there is no conflicting name.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customview: SDKCustomView = SDKCustomView()

    func CustomView(view: AnyObject!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rintaro, the second option worked for me i.e. typealias.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems in swift you can also explicitly call the init function.

Instead of calling:

```
var customview : CustomView = CustomView()
```

you can call:

```
var customview : CustomView = CustomView.init()
```

This works in my Playground, let me know how it works out for you. This would allow you to use your function named as it is.

Comment: Thanks @Chackle for quick response and new information about swift, but unfortunately, it did not resolved my problem, it still gives the same error.